# Python 3x query data using dates from datepicker dialog

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter, sqlite, datepicker, calendar

One last attempt to solve this problem. I have a Python program that queries the database using a default rundate to today - timedelta(7). I have created a datepicker to be opened using a menu button if the user want to choose their own dates to query.  I am having problems figuring out the query that will integrate the dates chosen by the datepicker into the program.

The datepicker works fine as I am able to print the start and end dates that are chosen using

```
def submit(): 
        start = self.result1.strftime("%m/%d/%Y")
        end = self.result2.strftime("%m/%d/%Y") 
        print(start, end)
```

I assume that the "print(start, end)" will have to be changed to "return(start,end)" to incorporate it into the main query but I could be wrong.

The initial query and top part of the interface is

```
import pyodbc
from datetime import date, timedelta
from tkinter import *
from tkinter.ttk import *
import calendar
from decimal import *
import sqlite3
import os 
import pick
db = r"M:\CWA_DB\WPTS\WPTS_Prod\WPTS_PROD_be.accdb"
conn = pyodbc.connect('Driver={Microsoft Access Driver (*.mdb, *.accdb)};Dbq='+db)
cur = conn.cursor()

#Rundate, 7 days ago
rundate = date.today() - timedelta(7)
print(rundate)

#Query permits made effective since rundate
query = '''select `NPDES_ID`, `EffectiveDate`, `FacilityName`, `StateFacilityID`, `City`, `CountyName`
        from Permits 
        where `EffectiveDate` >= ?
        order by `NPDES_ID`'''

IDS=[]
FacCodes=[]
PermStrings=[]
PayStrings=[]
OwnerStrings=[]
MTB=[]
MTG=[]
MTR=[]
SWC=[]
MT0=[]
count=0

#for each row in result of query
for row in cur.execute(query, (rundate)):
    try:
        d= row[1].strftime('%m/%d/%Y')
    except:
        d=""

#create a display string with the appropriate information permit # - date -  facility name - city, county
    for i in range(len(row)):
        if not row[i]:
            row[i] = ""

    permitstring=row[0]+" | "+d+"\t | "+row[2]+"\t | "+row[4]+", "+row[5]+" County"
    IDS.append(row[0])
    tempid=row[0]

    #add the index to the appropriate permit type array, used to display seperately
    if tempid[0:3]=="MTB":
        MTB.append(count)
    if tempid[0:3]=="MTG":
        MTG.append(count)
    if tempid[0:4]=="MTR0":
        MTR.append(count)
    if tempid[0:3]=="MT0" or tempid[0:3]=="MT4" or tempid[0:3]=="MTX":
        MT0.append(count)
    if tempid[0:4]=="MTR1":
        SWC.append(count)
    FacCodes.append(row[3])
    PermStrings.append(permitstring)
    count+=1

WPTSInv=[]

#get the owners for the permits
for i in range(len(IDS)):   
    query = '''select `Owner`
            from Owners 
            where `StateFacilityID` = ?'''
for row in cur.execute(query, (str(FacCodes[i]))):
    #create an owner name string for the facility ID
    OwnerStrings.append("Owner: "+row[0])

#get payments on the permits
for i in range(len(IDS)):   
paydate = date.today() - timedelta(60)
query = '''select `AmountPaid_credit`, `PayComment`, `DateReceived`, `WPTSinvoiceNo`
            from Payments 
            where `NPDES_ID` = ? and `DateReceived` >= ?'''
PayStrings.append("\tPayment Received")
for row in cur.execute(query, (IDS[i],paydate)):
    WPTSInv.append(row[3])
    d= row[2].strftime('%m/%d/%Y')
    #create a payment string 
    PayStrings[i]="\t$"+str(round(Decimal(row[0]),2))+" | "+d+" | "+row[1]  

#Initiate interface 
root = Tk() 
master = Frame(root, name='master') 
master.pack(fill=BOTH) 
root.geometry("800x800+300+100")
root.title('WeeklyReport')

menu_bar = Menu(root)
def exit():
    root.destroy()

def GetCalendar():
    os.system("Pick.py")

root.wait_window

filemenu = Menu(menu_bar, tearoff=0)
menu_bar.add_cascade(label="File", menu=filemenu)
filemenu.add_command(label="Exit", command=exit)

datemenu = Menu(menu_bar)
menu_bar.add_command(label='Change Date', command=GetCalendar)

root.config(menu=menu_bar) 

# start the app
if __name__ == "__main__":
    master.mainloop()
```

I have searched high and low for a solution but have not had much luck. I am sure others would be helped by an answer (even if the answer is that what I am trying to do is impossible)

Comment: Are you simply asking how to pass parameters into a query?

Comment: Pretty much - I think some kind of if-then so I can use rundate for either the initial today-delta(7) or the start/end dates picked by the datepicker. I just don't know how to format the query or where to insert it

Comment: @Brian Can you help?

Comment: I am getting closer! I have figured how to choose between timedelta(7) and opening the calendar dialog by using a message box  ....
#def RundateMessagebox():
    def GetCalendar():
     os.system("Pick.py")
    def rundate1():
        result = tkinter.messagebox.askyesno(title="Rundate", message="back 7 days?")
      if result == True:
        rundate1 = date.today() - timedelta(7)
        #print(rundate1)
        return rundate1
    else:
        GetCalendar()         
rundate = rundate1().... but still need help applying the calendar returns